# ASP.NET Set RadioButton to Select by a String Value

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I have a `RadioButton` control with `3` buttons.

I am retrieving a value from SharePoint list, and to select the RR control according to the value retrieved.

Which of the following is the correct method to use?

```
ResignationTypeRBList.SelectedValue = _request.ResignationType;
ResignationTypeRBList.SelectedItem  = _request.ResignationType;
ResignationTypeRBList.SelectedIndex = _request.ResignationType;
```

---

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ResignationTypeRBList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Resignation" Value="Resignation" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="NPL" Value="NPL"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Others" Value="Others"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting Value from Sharepoint list, then assign that to SelectedValue

```
ResignationTypeRBList.SelectedValue = "NPL";
```